# objective-c uisearchbar only allows one character at a time

Tags: objective-c, keyboard, uisearchbar

I have created the following code but there's still one thing that's bugging me.  For some reason, when I press any key on the keyboard, it immediately goes away, my cancel bar is disabled, but the code works and it correctly sorts and displays the cells in my table view that have those letters that the user typed in, though only one at a time.  Is there something I'm missing?  Thanks.

Edit:

Here's some code that I'm using.  Might help figure this out.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [self headerView];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [[self headerView] frame].size.height;
}

- (UIView *)headerView
{
if (headerView)
    return headerView;

float w = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
CGRect evHeaderFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, w, 45.0);
theSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45)];

theSearchBar.showsCancelButton=YES;
theSearchBar.autocorrectionType=UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
theSearchBar.autocapitalizationType=UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
theSearchBar.delegate = self;

headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:evHeaderFrame];
[headerView addSubview:theSearchBar];

searching = NO;

return headerView;
[headerView release];
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
if(searching)
    return;
searching = YES;

NSLog(@"Search Bar Text Did Begin Editing");
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
NSLog(@"Did End Editing");
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

[copyListOfItems removeAllObjects];

if([searchText length] > 0) {
    NSLog(@"Search Length is greater than 0");
    searching = YES;
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    [self searchTableView];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Search Length is less than 1");
    searching = NO;
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}

[self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar {

[self searchTableView];
}

- (void) searchTableView {

NSString *searchText = theSearchBar.text;
NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < [customArray count]; i++){
    NSRange titleResultsRange = [[[customArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0] rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
        //NSLog(@"%@ , %@",searchText,[customArray objectAtIndex:i]);
        [copyListOfItems addObject:[customArray objectAtIndex:i]];
}
//NSLog(@"CopyListOfItems : %@",copyListOfItems);
[searchArray release];
searchArray = nil;
}

- (void) doneSearching_Clicked:(id)sender {

theSearchBar.text = @"";
NSLog(@"RESIGN FIRST RESPONDER");
[theSearchBar resignFirstResponder];

searching = NO;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;

[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Looks like the problem was the [self.tableView reloadData];.  Looks like I'll have to find a new way to put the search bar on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding it in `Section Header`, try adding it on the `Tableview` Header.

It worked for me.

Comment: It would be nice to have it as a section header, though, so when you scroll down the tableview, the search bar anchors to the top of the visible table cells.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `NSLog(@"resign keybord");` just before `[searchBar resignFirstResponder];` and see if it shows something in console. If yes, try to figure out why that function gets called. Check out connections in NIB file and also delegates.

Comment: Tried that, doesn't seem to tell me anything.  I added my code to my original post.

Comment: Do you have <UISearchBarDelegate> in your .h file?
Something like @interface ClassName : NSObject<UISearchBarDelegate>{...

Just guessing.

Comment: @interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchBarDelegate>{

Comment: Yup, I do have that delegate in my .h file.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem, the searching of the data is causing the slow down of the UIKeyboard, as for every character entered, you are immediately searching the data. Try only searching the data on return?

Comment: Well, the slow down might be an issue, but I'd really like it to update as the user types in the search text.

Comment: I've found that even when I remove the code that searches through the data, it still only allows me to type one character at a time.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you are reloading the whole TableView which holds the UISearchBar once a filtering is made.(which is made on each character change in searchBar). So probably you should limit the reload to the section which holds the data and shouldn't reload the section containing UISearchBar.

Obj C:

```
[tableViewOutlet reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[indexPath section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Swift 2:

```
tableViewOutlet.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: section), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
```