# UISearchBar, crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone

This is kind of a weird error and not sure where to start.  We have a UISearchBar that used to work.  I don't believe we touched any of the code looking at Subversion.  It stopped working all of a sudden in the simulator.  When I try typing anything in, I automatically get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  I tried running with Instruments with Zombies and no information was provided.  I then tried running it on the device, and it works fine.  Any thoughts?

Also, I noticed that the new Xcode update has iPad 5.0 simulator.  I tried it in that, and it works fine as well.  In a slightly separate but related question, I noticed that in that view where my View is presented, certain views are different in the ipad 4.3 simulator and ipad 5.0 simulator.  How does one go troubleshooting something like that?  Or did the way that views are handled through push/pop/addSubview change between iOS 4 and iOS 5?  Thanks.

Comment: Post a stack trace for the crash, if you can. XC4.2 does terribly with stack traces sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

You are probably releasing the memory too early... I looked for problems similar to yours and most of the problems that have your description are due to releasing the memory too early. You didn't provide alot of code to work with, so the best I can do is give you a link that may help you out. [objective-c uisearchbar only allows one character at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353747/objective-c-uisearchbar-only-allows-one-character-at-a-time)

Answer (score 0):

Set UISearchBar delegate to nil in dealloc method of view controller.